Why doesn't the padding attribute affect my app on a physical device, even though it works in the Android Studio design simulator?
I've encountered an issue where the padding attribute appears correctly in the Android Studio design simulator, but when I run the app on a physical device, the padding doesn't show.
This used to work perfectly fine before, but I've recently updated my Android Studio version. Could this issue be related to the update, or is it possibly due to Android 14?
Additional Information:
Android Studio Version: 2024.1.1 (koala)
Device: Samsung galaxy S23+

Can you post the XML of your layout?
